# brake for-loop when condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have pandas `df`. Dataframe contains information about various products and whether this product had sales in particular month

```
product  2021-01-01 00:00:00  2021-02-01 00:00:00  2021-03-01 00:00:00  2021-04-01 00:00:00  2021-05-01 00:00:00  2021-06-01 00:00:00  2021-07-01 00:00:00  2021-08-01 00:00:00  2021-09-01 00:00:00  2021-10-01 00:00:00  2021-11-01 00:00:00  2021-12-01 00:00:00  2022-01-01 00:00:00  2022-02-01 00:00:00  2022-03-01 00:00:00  2022-04-01 00:00:00  2022-05-01 00:00:00  2022-06-01 00:00:00  2022-07-01 00:00:00  2022-08-01 00:00:00
2          C                    1                    1                    1                    1                    1                    1                    1                    1                    1                    0                    0                    0                    0                    0                    0                    0                    0                    0                    0                    0
3          D                    1                    1                    1                    1                    1                    1                    1                    1                    1                    1                    1                    1                    1                    0                    0                    0                    0                    0                    0                    0
```

I would like to return list of the last dats when the product have been sold.
For example for product '''C''' it will be '''2021-10-01''', for product '''D''' it will be '''2022-02-01'''

I run for loop but it returns me all dates where val >0. (as expected)
How can I adjust loop that it will return me only the last date?

```
for col in df.iloc[:,1:].columns:
    for val in df[col]:
        if val>0:
            print(col)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't loop. Reshape with [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and get the max date per sold product with [`groupby.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html):

```
tmp = df.set_index('product').rename_axis(columns='date')

out = (tmp[tmp.eq(1)].stack().reset_index('date')
       .groupby('product')['date'].max()
      )
```

Output:

```
product
C    2021-09-01 00:00:00
D    2022-01-01 00:00:00
Name: date, dtype: object
```